# maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object -runtime error

Tags: python, arrays, excel, numpy, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter
import openpyxl as px
import numpy as np
from xlwt import Workbook
from os.path import expanduser

home = expanduser("~")

def read_survey():  
    df_appliance=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/nidi/Desktop/New folder/app_info.csv')
    df_appliance.fillna(0, inplace=True)
    return df_appliance

df_appliance=read_survey()

def map_appliance_info(df_appliance):

    oven_usage=[]
    #oven_type_radio=[]
    oven_type_micro=[]
    oven_type_oven=[]
    tube_light_count=[]
    led_count=[]
    incand_count=[]
    cfl_count=[]

    for i in range(len(df_appliance['sur_key'].values)):                   

        if df_appliance['oven-type'].values[i]=='radio':
            #oven_type_radio.append(1)
            oven_type_micro.append(0)
            oven_type_oven.append(0)
        elif df_appliance['oven-type'].values[i]=='micro':
            #oven_type_radio.append(0)
            oven_type_micro.append(1)
            oven_type_oven.append(0)
        elif df_appliance['oven-type'].values[i]=='oven':
            #oven_type_radio.append(0)
            oven_type_micro.append(0)
            oven_type_oven.append(1)
        else:
            #oven_type_radio.append(0)
            oven_type_micro.append(0)
            oven_type_oven.append(0)

        if df_appliance['oven-ousg'].values[i]=='little':
            oven_usage.append(1)
        elif df_appliance['oven-ousg'].values[i]=='defrost':
            oven_usage.append(5)
        elif df_appliance['oven-ousg'].values[i]=='mod':
            oven_usage.append(12)
        elif df_appliance['oven-ousg'].values[i]=='ext':
            oven_usage.append(30)
        else:
            oven_usage.append(0)

        #return df_appliance_mapped

        df_appliance_mapped = map_appliance_info(df_appliance)

result=np.array(df_appliance_mapped)
```

This is my code. when printing map_appliance_info(df_appliance) i am getting the error-

File "E:/iisc/code/try.py", line 69, in map_appliance_info
    df_appliance_mapped = map_appliance_info(df_appliance)

File "E:/iisc/code/try.py", line 35, in map_appliance_info
    for i in range(len(df_appliance['sur_key'].values)):

File "C:\Users\nidi\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 1957, in **getitem**
    indexer = convert_to_index_sliceable(self, key)

File "C:\Users\nidi\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1658, in convert_to_index_sliceable
    elif isinstance(key, compat.string_types):

RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object

can anybody help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you are calling `pd.read_excel`, you must have Pandas installed.
Therefore the easiest way to merge the data is to call [`pd.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) on two DataFrames:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({0: [1, 1, 0, 0], 1: [0, 0, 1, 1], 2: [1, 2, 1, 5], 3: [1, 2, 3, 4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({0: [0, 1, 1, 0], 1: [1, 0, 0, 1], 2: [1, 2, 1, 5]})
result = pd.merge(df2, df1, on=[0,1,2])
print(result.values)
```

prints

```
[[0 1 1 3]
 [1 0 2 2]
 [1 0 1 1]
 [0 1 5 4]]
```

---

If `df_appliance_mapped` is the second DataFrame, you could use:

```
first_df = pd.read_excel('E:/iisc/code/energy_usage_appliance.xlsx',0,header=None)
result = pd.merge(df_appliance_mapped, first_df, on=[0,1,2])
```

Comment: but will it work as the len of the files are not same.
i have to append the 4th column if the columns match.

Comment: and its showing me an error-
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute '_values'